# Creating groups of tests with Ctest

Tags: unit-testing, cmake, ctest

I am trying to group individual ctest tests together but have so far been unsuccessful. For example if I have the following tests:
add_test(test1)
add_test(test2)
add_test(test3)

I would like to group them into a test suite that will upload to a dashboard as one test.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe helpful for you can be the possibelity to set different labels to test. Look at that possibelity (goes over set Property)